# Android shopping cart button action

Tags: android, json, listview

[image]
I am new to android i have shopping list and add button in the list when the add is clicked i need to add product to cartpage. how to add the product to cart in android. where i need to write the button action code and get all its content iin net page.

Custom List Adapter

```
public class CustomListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Activity activity;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private List<Movie> movieItems;
private CustomListAdapter listener;
ImageLoader imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();

public CustomListAdapter(Activity activity, List<Movie> movieItems) {
    this.activity = activity;
    this.movieItems = movieItems;
    this.listener = listener;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return movieItems.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int location) {
    return movieItems.get(location);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (inflater == null)
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (convertView == null)
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);

    if (imageLoader == null)
        imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();
    NetworkImageView thumbNail = (NetworkImageView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
    TextView title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
    TextView rating = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rating);
    //TextView genre = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.genre);
    TextView year = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.releaseYear);
    Button btnAddToCart = (Button) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.btnAddToCart);
    btnAddToCart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //Intent in = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            Intent intent = new Intent(CustomListAdapter.this.activity, MainActivity.class);

            //Toast.makeText(activity.getApplicationContext(), "Added to Cart.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    });
    // getting movie data for the row
    final Movie m = movieItems.get(position);

    // thumbnail image
    thumbNail.setImageUrl(m.getThumbnailUrl(), imageLoader);

    // title
    title.setText(m.getTitle());

    // rating
    rating.setText("Quantity" +
            ": " + String.valueOf(m.getRating())+"gm");

    // genre
    String genreStr = "";
    for (String str : m.getGenre()) {
        genreStr += str + ", ";
    }
//  genreStr = genreStr.length() > 0 ? genreStr.substring(0,
    //      genreStr.length() - 2) : genreStr;
    //genre.setText(genreStr);

    // release year
    year.setText("Rs"+"."+String.valueOf(m.getYear()));
    btnAddToCart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(CustomListAdapter.this.activity, ViewCart.class);
            CustomListAdapter.this.activity.startActivity(intent);

            //Toast.makeText(activity.getApplicationContext(), "Added to Cart.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        //  listener.onAddToCartPressed(m);
        }
    });
    return convertView;
}
public interface CustomListAdapterListener {
    public void onAddToCartPressed(Movie m);
}
}
```

Main Activity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
// Log tag
private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

// Movies json url
private static final String url = "http://xxx[![enter image description here][1]][1]/mobile_app/products.json";
private ProgressDialog pDialog;
private List<Movie> movieList = new ArrayList<Movie>();
private ListView listView;
private CustomListAdapter adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    adapter = new CustomListAdapter(this, movieList);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    // Showing progress dialog before making http request
    pDialog.setMessage("Fetching Products...");
    pDialog.show();

    // changing action bar color
    //getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(
    //      new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#1b1b1b")));

    // Creating volley request obj

    JsonArrayRequest movieReq = new JsonArrayRequest(url,
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                    hidePDialog();

                    // Parsing json
                    for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                        try {

                            JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                            Movie movie = new Movie();
                            movie.setTitle(obj.getString("title"));
                            movie.setThumbnailUrl(obj.getString("image"));
                            movie.setRating(((Number) obj.get("rating"))
                                    .doubleValue());
                            movie.setYear(obj.getInt("releaseYear"));

                            // Genre is json array
                            JSONArray genreArry = obj.getJSONArray("genre");
                            ArrayList<String> genre = new ArrayList<String>();
                            for (int j = 0; j < genreArry.length(); j++) {
                                genre.add((String) genreArry.get(j));
                            }
                            movie.setGenre(genre);

                            // adding movie to movies array
                            movieList.add(movie);

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }

                    // notifying list adapter about data changes
                    // so that it renders the list view with updated data
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
            hidePDialog();

        }
    });

    // Adding request to request queue
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(movieReq);
}


@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    hidePDialog();
}

private void hidePDialog() {
    if (pDialog != null) {
        pDialog.dismiss();
        pDialog = null;
    }

   }

  // @Override
     public void onAddToCartPressed(Movie product) {
   //   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
     //        " added to cart!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   [enter image description here][1] }

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

Comment: check it you'll get what you are searching for [Click here](http://www.androiddom.com/2011/02/android-shopping-cart-tutorial.html)

Comment: Can you provide any other sample

Comment: What you question is? Change the shape of button?

Comment: i need to add product to cart. i need to set action for button and product sshould be added in cart page